# Suspicion Fell On

Tags: meaning, grammar, usage

I have a question about the usage of the phrase "*fall on*" in this [NY Times article](http://www.nytimes.com/2016/02/25/nyregion/michael-skakels-lawyer-says-trial-in-killing-of-martha-moxley-wasnt-fair.html?_r=0):

> Suspicion ***fell on*** the Skakel family, and later on Ken Littleton, a tutor who had just started a new job teaching the Skakel children.

I checked some dictionaries and did not find a definition that would fit this usage of "*fall on*".  As NY Times are not likely to be wrong with their writing usages, could the usage of "*fall on*" be technical newspaper lingo?

Answer (score 4):

According to the Cambridge Dictionaries Online (http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/fall-on-sb),

**fall on sb** — phrasal verb

When suspicion falls on a particular person, people think that they may be guilty of doing something bad.

*Example: He was the last person to see the woman alive, and suspicion immediately fell on him.*

That part in the NY Times article means that people thought the Skakel family might be guilty.

Answer (score -4):

it means the Skakel family became suspicious

Comment: Do you mean the *family* became suspicious of *someone*, or the family *was suspected*?

Comment: @Sina That should be a new question!